# (electron.js) npm start does nothing

Tags: node.js, terminal, electron, npm-start, kali-linux

I am facing an issue with electron while i try to start my app. basically I did an `npm start` but it absolutely did nothing except printing out these 2 lines :

> "> test@1.0.0 start /home/devfreak/Documents/Desktop Development/test"
>
> "> electron ."

My app didn't start at all.

So, What's the fix?

**Please note**

1. My node version is v10.20.1
2. My npm version is 6.14.4
3. this issue is not solved by what you'll see here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15467 because i am using node 10 and the default `windowsHide` option in node 10 is already set to false
4. I am using Kali Linux i386 (32 bit)

   ```
                             ## Additional Information ##
   ```

Before this one I had another issue  with npm start -
"The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly"
But i figured it out by changing the ownership of the directory using `CHOWN`

Please help me. Thanks !